# In Photon Bolt, how to send List of int data in a token along with event?

Tags: photon

My codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Bolt;
using UdpKit;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class ListOfIntToken : IProtocolToken
{
    public List<int> intList;
    public int byteArraySize;

    public void Read(UdpPacket packet)
    {
        byteArraySize = packet.ReadInt();
        var objectBytes = packet.ReadByteArray(byteArraySize);
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        mStream.Write(objectBytes, 0, objectBytes.Length);
        mStream.Position = 0;
        intList = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as List<int>;
    }

    public void Write(UdpPacket packet)
    {
        var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, intList);
        //byte[] bytes = userId.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
        var byteArray = mStream.ToArray();
        byteArraySize = byteArray.Length;
        packet.WriteInt(byteArraySize);
        packet.WriteByteArray(byteArray);
    }
}
```

I have two clients running A and B. A is server. Both are sending the event with this token but with different data for testing. In `Write` method I print the `byteArraySize` out, and when the data are received on server I print them out too. The `byteArraySize` for A's data is 0, and the time it's printed is before the printing line in`Write` method, where the size was 221. However for B's data the size was correct. What may causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
public void Read(UdpPacket packet)
{
    intList.Clear();

    if (packet.ReadBool()) // check if we have data to read
    {
        var total = packet.ReadInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            intList.Add(packet.ReadInt());
        }
    }
}

public void Write(UdpPacket packet)
{
    var total = intList.Count;
    
    if (packet.WriteBool(total > 0)) // Write bool to signal we have some data
    {
        packet.WriteInt(total);

        foreach (var item in intList)
        {
            packet.WriteInt(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The weird bug is caused by assigning to a wrong variable. It's been corrected in the question.